# automatically export Google Contacts data to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

I want to automatically fetch contact info from my Google Contacts and display it in a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

I have used the following code for fetching and displaying fullName

```
`function getName() { // Gets the names of everyone in the 'GUIDES' label in Google Contacts
  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('GUIDES');
  var contacts = group.getContacts(), output = [];  
  for(var i = 0, iLen = contacts.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    var fullname = contacts[i].getFullName();    
    if(fullname) {
      output.push([fullname]);
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(4, 3, output.length, 1).setValues(output);
}`
```

This works correctly and returns all names in the group labelled "Guides"

I also want to return email addresses. When I use the same code with .getEmails instead of .getFullName it returns the email field but not the string I want.

I have tried `.getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL);` with `.getAddress()` as below but it doesn't work. I get the Error

> Cannot find function getAddress in object EmailField.

```
`function getAddress(){
 var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('GUIDES');
 var contact = group.getContacts(),output = [];  
  for(var i = 0, iLen = contact.length; i < iLen; i++) {
 var addresses = contact[i].getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL);
    if(addresses) {
      output.push([addresses.getAddress()]);
     } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(4, 4, output.length, 1).setValues(output);
}
   `
```

I would like the email address for the field to be displayed, not the field itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values retrieved by `getEmails()` is an array. So how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
output.push([addresses.getAddress()]);
```

To:

```
output.push([addresses.map(function(e) {return e.getAddress()}).join(",")]);
```

#### Note:

- If empty values are retrieved from the modified script, please also try to modify as follows.

  - From:

    ```
    var addresses = contact[i].getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL);
    ```
  - To:

    ```
    var addresses = contact[i].getEmails();
    ```

#### References:

- [getEmails(label)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#getemailslabel)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Worked perfectly